# Proxy and reflection Code - looking for exception handling no try/catch

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a Redis project and I would love to know where I am likely to run into Unhandled Exceptions in the following code.

A General Review would be great, don't hold back.

This is code for Intercepting using proxies, and uses a considerable amount of Reflection to resolve unknown types.

I am posting the following link to Github so if you need to see all the code related you can do so there: [Full Project Code](https://github.com/DemgelOpenSource/DemgelRedis)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Castle.Core.Internal;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using DemgelRedis.Common;
using DemgelRedis.Interfaces;
using DemgelRedis.ObjectManager.Attributes;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace DemgelRedis.ObjectManager.Proxy
{
    public class ChangeTrackerInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        private readonly IDatabase _database;
        private readonly RedisObjectManager _redisObjectManager;
        private readonly IRedisBackup _redisBackup;
        private readonly string _id;

        private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _listeners; 

        protected internal bool Processed { private get; set; }
        private bool Transient { get; }
        protected internal object ParentProxy { private get; set; }

        public ChangeTrackerInterceptor(
            IDatabase redisDatabase, 
            RedisObjectManager redisObjectManager,
            IRedisBackup redisBackup,
            string id,
            bool transient)
        {
            _database = redisDatabase;
            _redisObjectManager = redisObjectManager;
            _redisBackup = redisBackup;
            _id = id;

            _listeners = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            Transient = transient;
        }

        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var cAttr =
                   ParentProxy?.GetType().BaseType?
                       .GetProperties()
                       .SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetValue(ParentProxy, null) == invocation.Proxy) ??
                   invocation.Proxy;

            if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("Add", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                var cPropertyInfo = cAttr as PropertyInfo;

                if (cPropertyInfo != null)
                {
                    if (cPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("IList"))
                    {
                        DoAddListItem(invocation, cPropertyInfo);
                        invocation.Proceed();
                        return;
                    }

                    // This code us currently irrelavent (WIP)
                    if (cPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("IDictionary"))
                    {
                        // Do Set Dictionary Item
                        invocation.Proceed();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("set_Item") && invocation.Arguments.Length == 2)
            {
                var cPropertyInfo = cAttr as PropertyInfo;

                if (cPropertyInfo != null)
                {
                    if (cPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("IList"))
                    {
                        DoSetListItem(invocation, cPropertyInfo);
                    }
                    else if (cPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("IDictionary"))
                    {
                        // This code is irrelavent (WIP)
                        // Do Set Dictionary Item
                        DoSetDictionaryItem(invocation, cPropertyInfo);
                    }
                    invocation.Proceed();
                    return;
                }
            }

            // if it gets this far, we are likely to be setting a property in an IRedisObject
            // We cannot process IRedisObjects here if we are trying to set a Proxies object
            // With a new IRedisObject, we need to handle that differently
            if (!(invocation.Arguments[0] is IRedisObject)
                && Processed)
            {
                if (cAttr.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IRedisObject)))
                {
                    // This is a single item within an IRedisObject... it will be saved as a hash
                    var key = new RedisKeyObject(cAttr.GetType(), _id);
                    // Need to get the property name of the IRedisObject this is being set in
                    // I might be missing something here, but this works... TODO look for faster lookup
                    var property =
                        invocation.Method.ReflectedType?.GetProperties()
                            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.SetMethod.Name == invocation.Method.Name);

                    ITypeConverter converter;
                    if (property != null && _redisObjectManager.TypeConverters.TryGetValue(property.PropertyType, out converter))
                    {
                        var ret = new HashEntry(property.Name, converter.ToWrite(invocation.Arguments[0]));

                        _redisBackup?.RestoreHash(_database, key);
                        _redisBackup?.UpdateHashValue(ret, key);

                        _database.HashSet(key.RedisKey, ret.Name, ret.Value);
                    }
                }

                //Notify(invocation, key);
            }

            invocation.Proceed();
        }

        private object CreateProxy(IRedisObject argument, out RedisKeyObject key)
        {
            var argumentType = argument.GetType();
            key = new RedisKeyObject(argumentType, string.Empty);

            GenerateId(key, argument);

            var newArgument = _redisObjectManager.RetrieveObjectProxy(argumentType, key.Id, _database, argument, Transient);

            var prop = argumentType.GetProperties()
                .SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetCustomAttributes().Any(y => y is RedisIdKey));

            if (prop != null && prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                prop.SetValue(newArgument, key.Id);
            }
            else if (prop != null && prop.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
            {
                prop.SetValue(newArgument, Guid.Parse(key.Id));
            }

            return newArgument;
        }

        private void DoAddListItem(IInvocation invocation, PropertyInfo prop)
        {
            var listKey = new RedisKeyObject(prop, _id);

            // Make sure the list is Restored
            _redisBackup?.RestoreList(_database, listKey);

            var redisObject = invocation.Arguments[0] as IRedisObject;
            if (redisObject != null)
            {
                RedisKeyObject key;
                if (!(invocation.Arguments[0] is IProxyTargetAccessor))
                {
                    // Create the Proxy 
                    var proxy = CreateProxy(redisObject, out key);
                    invocation.Arguments[0] = proxy;
                }
                else
                {
                    key = new RedisKeyObject(redisObject.GetType(), string.Empty);
                    GenerateId(key, invocation.Arguments[0]);
                }

                if (!Processed) return;
                _redisBackup?.AddListItem(_database, listKey, key.RedisKey);

                _database.ListRightPush(listKey.RedisKey, key.RedisKey);
                _redisObjectManager.SaveObject(invocation.Arguments[0], key.Id, _database);
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO to better checks for casting to RedisValue
                _redisBackup?.AddListItem(_database, listKey, (RedisValue) invocation.Arguments[0]);
                _database.ListRightPush(listKey.RedisKey, (RedisValue) invocation.Arguments[0]);
            }
        }

        private void DoSetDictionaryItem(IInvocation invocation, PropertyInfo prop)
        {
            var key = new RedisKeyObject(prop, _id);
        }

        private void DoSetListItem(IInvocation invocation, PropertyInfo prop)
        {
            var listKey = new RedisKeyObject(prop, _id);

            // Make sure the list is Restored
            _redisBackup?.RestoreList(_database, listKey);

            // We will need the Original value no matter what
            var accessor = (IProxyTargetAccessor)invocation.Proxy;
            var original = (accessor.DynProxyGetTarget() as IList)?[(int)invocation.Arguments[0]];
            if (original == null) return;

            // We are checking if the new item set to the list is actually a Proxy (if not created it)
            var redisObject = invocation.Arguments[1] as IRedisObject;
            if (redisObject != null)
            {
                var originalKey = new RedisKeyObject(original.GetType(), string.Empty);
                GenerateId(originalKey, original);

                RedisKeyObject key;
                if (!(invocation.Arguments[1] is IProxyTargetAccessor))
                {
                    // Create the Proxy 
                    var proxy = CreateProxy(redisObject, out key);
                    invocation.Arguments[1] = proxy;
                }
                else
                {
                    key = new RedisKeyObject(redisObject.GetType(), string.Empty);
                    GenerateId(key, invocation.Arguments[1]);
                }

                if (!Processed) return;
                _redisBackup?.UpdateListItem(_database, listKey, originalKey.RedisKey, key.RedisKey);

                _database.ListRemove(listKey.RedisKey, originalKey.RedisKey, 1);
                _database.ListRightPush(listKey.RedisKey, key.RedisKey);
                _redisObjectManager.SaveObject(invocation.Arguments[1], key.Id, _database);
            }
            else
            {
                _redisBackup?.UpdateListItem(_database, listKey, (RedisValue) original,
                    (RedisValue) invocation.Arguments[1]);
                _database.ListRemove(listKey.RedisKey, (RedisValue) original, 1);
                _database.ListRightPush(listKey.RedisKey, (RedisValue) invocation.Arguments[1]);
            }
        }

        private void GenerateId(RedisKeyObject key, object argument)
        {
            var redisIdAttr =
                argument.GetType().GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(
                    x => x.GetCustomAttributes().Any(a => a is RedisIdKey));
            var value = redisIdAttr?.GetValue(argument, null);

            if (redisIdAttr != null && redisIdAttr.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                if (((string) value).IsNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    var newId = _database.StringIncrement($"demgelcounter:{key.CounterKey}");
                    key.Id = newId.ToString();
                    redisIdAttr.SetValue(argument, key.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    key.Id = (string) value;
                }
            }
            else if (redisIdAttr != null && redisIdAttr.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
            {
                if ((Guid) value == new Guid())
                {
                    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                    key.Id = guid.ToString();
                    redisIdAttr.SetValue(argument, guid);
                }
                else
                {
                    key.Id = ((Guid) value).ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("RedisIdKey needs to be either Guid or String");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`private void GenerateId(RedisKeyObject key, object argument)`**

Here you are mixing styles by using both the null-conditional operator `?` and the "default" `null` check, although it would be possible to stick to one style.

This method would benefit in speed and readability if you would have a guard condition for checking `redisIdAttr == null`. This would lead to less checks for `redisIdAttr != null` and also the null-conditional operator wouldn't be needed. In addition the current thrown `ArgumentException` wouldn't be thrown if `redisIdAttr == null` which doesn't fit for that condition.

You are doing some repeated casts which could be omitted by introducing a variable.

The checking of the `Guid` should be simplified by checking `== Guid.Empty`. There is no need to create a new `Guid` each time.

Like so

```
private void GenerateId(RedisKeyObject key, object argument)
{
    var redisIdAttr =
        argument.GetType().GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(
            x => x.GetCustomAttributes().Any(a => a is RedisIdKey));

    if (redisAttr == null) { return; } // or throw an exception

    var value = redisIdAttr.GetValue(argument, null);

    if (redisIdAttr.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        var currentValue = (string)value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue))
        {
            var newId = _database.StringIncrement($"demgelcounter:{key.CounterKey}");
            key.Id = newId.ToString();
            redisIdAttr.SetValue(argument, key.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            key.Id = currentValue;
        }
    }
    else if (redisIdAttr.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
    {
        var guid = (Guid)value;
        if (guid == Guid.Empty)
        {
            guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            key.Id = guid.ToString();
            redisIdAttr.SetValue(argument, guid);
        }
        else
        {
            key.Id = guid.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("RedisIdKey needs to be either Guid or String");
    }
}
```

If this method is used a lot, you should consider to store the `string` and `Guid` type in a class variable.

---

**`private object CreateProxy(IRedisObject argument, out RedisKeyObject key)`**

Here you are checking against `typeof(string)` and `typeof(Guid)` too, so you really should extract these types to class variables.

This method could benefit from a guard clause too.

Like so

```
private Type stringType = typeof(string);
private Type guidType = typeof(Guid);
private object CreateProxy(IRedisObject argument, out RedisKeyObject key)
{
    var argumentType = argument.GetType();
    key = new RedisKeyObject(argumentType, string.Empty);

    GenerateId(key, argument);

    var newArgument = _redisObjectManager.RetrieveObjectProxy(argumentType, key.Id, _database, argument, Transient);

    var prop = argumentType.GetProperties()
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetCustomAttributes().Any(y => y is RedisIdKey));
    if (prop == null) { return newArgument;}

    if (prop.PropertyType == stringType)
    {
        prop.SetValue(newArgument, key.Id);
    }
    else if (prop.PropertyType == guidType)
    {
        prop.SetValue(newArgument, Guid.Parse(key.Id));
    }

    return newArgument;
}
```

---

**`public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)`**

The first part could be improved by first checking if `cPropertyInfo != null` and then check for the names.

The usage of the null coalescing operator at the top would be more obvious  if placed on a new line to reduce the scrolling.

You are using two overloads of the `string.StartsWith()` method. If this is needed, then you should add a comment to describe **why** you need to use a different overload.

Like so

```
   public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var cAttr =
               ParentProxy?.GetType().BaseType?
                   .GetProperties()
                   .SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetValue(ParentProxy, null) == invocation.Proxy)  
               ??
               invocation.Proxy;

        var cPropertyInfo = cAttr as PropertyInfo;
        if (cPropertyInfo != null)
        {
            if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("Add", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                if (cPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("IList"))
                {
                    DoAddListItem(invocation, cPropertyInfo);
                    invocation.Proceed();
                    return;
                }

                // This code us currently irrelavent (WIP)
                if (cPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("IDictionary"))
                {
                    // Do Set Dictionary Item
                    invocation.Proceed();
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("set_Item") && invocation.Arguments.Length == 2)
            {
                if (cPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("IList"))
                {
                    DoSetListItem(invocation, cPropertyInfo);
                }
                else if (cPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("IDictionary"))
                {
                    // This code is irrelavent (WIP)
                    // Do Set Dictionary Item
                    DoSetDictionaryItem(invocation, cPropertyInfo);
                }
                invocation.Proceed();
                return;
            }                
        }
```

(this is only the start of the method)

---

**General**

- the `private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _listeners;` is never used except for when it is created in the constructor. You should remove it.
- comments should describe **why** something is done. For instance this comment

  > ```
  > // Create the Proxy 
  > var proxy = CreateProxy(redisObject, out key);
  > ```

  should be removed because it only adds noise to the code.